# Show that two vectors $u,v$ are linearly dependent if and only if their determinant is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have already shown that if U, V are linearly dependent, the determinant is zero, but when doing the return, I cannot arrive at that U and V are linearly dependent.

I only got to this in the demo

We assume that
$u_{1}v_{2}-v_{1}u_{2} = 0$

Let

$\lambda_{2}=-u_{1}$ e $\lambda_{1}=v_{1}$

Then:

-$\lambda_{2}v_{2}-\lambda_{1}u_{2}=0$

I have done this, I hope someone can help me ... I've been stuck in this part for a long time and I don't understand how to do it :C

Comment: Hint: we have $u_1=\frac{u_2}{v_2}v_1$ when $v_2\neq 0$ (and if $v_2=0$, then you can easily treat this case separately).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $U=(u_1,u_2)$ and $V=(v_1,v_2)$ are linearly dependent.
Then there exist scalars $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1U+c_2V=\textbf{0}$.

Now $c_1U+c_2V=\textbf{0}\implies c_1\begin{bmatrix} u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}=0$.

Thus $c_1u_1+c_2v_1=0,c_1u_2+c_2v_2=0$. Eliminating $c_1,c_2$ we get

$\det\begin{bmatrix} u_1 & v_1\\u_2& v_2\end{bmatrix}=u_1v_2-v_1u_2=0$.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by proving the contrapositive of the statement which is logically equivalent to the original. In other words, we need to prove that if the determinant is nonzero, then the vectors are linearly independent.

Suppose that $u_1v_2-v_1u_2\neq 0$. We know that $(u_1,u_2)\neq0$ and $(v_1,v_2)\neq0$ because that would make the determinant equal to 0.

Assume that there exist scalars $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha(u_1,u_2)+\beta(v_1,v_2)=0$.

We then have that $(\alpha u_1+\beta v_1,\alpha u_2+\beta v_2)=(0,0)$ which gives us the following equations:
$$\alpha u_1+\beta v_1=0$$
$$\alpha u_2+\beta v_2=0$$
We can multiply the first equation by $v_2$ and the second equation by $v_1$ to get these equations:
$$\alpha u_1v_2+\beta v_1v_2=0$$
$$\alpha v_1u_2+\beta v_1v_2=0$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first gives us:
$$\alpha(u_1v_2-v_1u_2)=0$$
By the assumption that $u_1v_2-v_1u_2\neq0$, we can divide both sides by $u_1v_2-v_1u_2$ to get that $\alpha=0$.

Since $(v_1,v_2)\neq0$, we have that at least one of $v_1$ or $v_2$ is not equal to zero.

If $v_1\neq0$, we can plug $\alpha=0$ into $\alpha u_1+\beta v_1=0$ to get that $\beta v_1=0$. Dividing by $v_1$ gives the desired result that $\beta=0$.
If $v_2\neq0$, we can do a similar process with the other equation.

We now have that the only scalars $\alpha,\beta$ that satisfy $\alpha(u_1,u_2)+\beta(v_1,v_2)=0$ are $\alpha=\beta=0$. Allowing us to conclude that $(u_1,u_2)$ and $(v_1,v_2)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I think this is backwards.  The OP is looking to prove non-zero determinant implies dependence, so the contrapositive would condition on independence.

Comment: @ErickWong You're right I just read it over again and I proved the wrong contrapositive lol.